# MS VS 2008 and C99

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, syntax, c99, c89

I read with interest the post "How universally is C99 supported ?". One of the comments therein points that Microsoft doesn't support C99. But the comment symbol // works with VS 2008 and this symbol is in C99. I have two questions:

1. To what extent VS 2008 support C99?
2. Is it ok in the same code to mix C89 and C99 syntax together? So if I write my code in C89 and then place a comment //. This means that I have mixed-coding. So what does the compiler do in such a case? Check my code first with c89 and then with C99 to accept that I use // for commenting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSVC supports very little of C99 in C mode.  The few things that it does (like '//' comments) are really extensions they've added to C90 mode that come from C++, which may happen to also be in C99. When compiling C code, MSVC treats '//' comments as an extension to C90, not that you're intermixing C90 code with C99 code.

You'll get 'better' C99 support by compiling your C files as C++ - in that way you'll get declarations that can be interspersed with statements and variable declarations in `for` statements that are scoped to the `for` loop, for example.

Microsoft seems to have zero interest in adding C99 support to MSVC - even as they add things from C99 to the C++ compiler mode (like `stdint.h` being added in VS2010) since some additional C99 things are being added to C++ in C++0x.

Comment: Thanks. I normally save my files with an extension c instead of cpp as I work in C. Does the extension makes a difference for the compiler? Strangely, it's not mentioned that MSVC has a C compiler; It just mentions C++ compiler.

Comment: The extension makes a difference by default - .c files are compiled in C mode, .cpp and .cxx files are compiled in C++ mode.  You can override this using the `/TP` or `/Tp<file>` to force compiling as C++ and `/TC` or `/Tc<file>` to force compiling as C: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx

Comment: This is interesting to know. Thanks.